# Indenting listings in Auctex

Tags: listings, indentation, auctex

I'm using the `listings` package to typeset some Python code. I don't seem to be able use the tab key in Auctex mode to indent my code within listings.

I'm new to both Emacs and Auctex, but the only solution extensive googling turned up was to use M-i. Unfortunately this is less than ideal since e.g. unindent with backspace does not work.

Could anybody help me get the tab key to work as expected within `listings` within Auctex?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Are you able to use the tab key to indent text other than `listings` related text? If so, then this question is not related to `listings`, and I would recommend changing the question to `Indenting with Auctex using the tab key`, and removing the `listings` tag.

Comment: Hmm..well as in most Emacs modes the tab key seems to be bound to something else. But I expected Auctex to be "intelligent" enough to recognise verbatim-like environments. I guess I'd have more luck in an Emacs forum but I thought I'd give tex.sx a shot, since it solves all my TeXnical questions :)